How can I validate JSON with JSON Schema using RESTeasy and Jackson?
Our tech stack is:

JBoss EAP 7
RESTeasy
Jackson

We generate OpenAPI (openapi.json) from the Java code using Eclipse MicroProfile API annotations and the Smallrye Maven plugin.
I have searched Stackoverflow (of course) and the Internet in general. But I can't seem to find any example of how to validate incoming JSON using JSON Schema (on a dedicated JSON Schema server).
Can anyone help me? In 2024, validation of data shouldn't be that exotic  ;-)

Did you ask ChatGPT, too?

No, I think the Stackoverflow community is smarter than ChatGTP  :-)

OK, because ChatGPT can provide the correct solution with proper prompt but i don't want to just copy/paste it as an answer here.

But you could publish the prompt here, that would be very helpful.
